# Multipeer Connectivity range and non ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

I just started coding Multipeer connectivity with objective c in xcode. I have a few questions about the basics.

1. What is the range with Multipeer Connectivity? So if I make a chat program, will the two devices only be able to communicate if they are on the wifi network, or will they still be able to communicate if they are across the globe?
2. Will the program work with an ios device and a non ios device, so they can send each other messages? If yes, are there any extra methods or code that I need to add?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I understand MPC works over bluetooth and wifi- so if you are on a home wifi network, or a University campus network, your peers should be able to see one another. MPCis not for using across the globe that I know of...
2. This is an iOS technology only, iBeacon works across multiple platforms (iOS, android).

But, depending on what you want, you could make your app use internet to go across the globe, and you might be able to use straight bluetooth to connecto to a non-iOS device, then hook into MPC.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Keith's answer above that MPC supports peer-to-peer Wifi as well. This means that the devices involved don't need to be connected to an access point to talk to each other.

Also, the framework protects the developer (and end user) from the underlying technology (bluetooth, WIFI, P2P WIFI) used. In a given "session" between any number of devices (currently only up to 8 supported), each device could be using a different technology to talk to the others.